# Xcode 6.1 Autolayout issue for 3.5in display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, iphone-4

I have a very strange issue with Autolayout. Check attacked screenshot, I am primary interested in that red topbar. I set all constraints, and it works pretty well for all sizes, except 3.5in.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

How is it possible something like this? Is this an Xcode bug?

Note: There are no constraints added programatically. Everything is right there, in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it proved to be some problems in the way I set constraints. Deleted all, and redoing them, solved the problem.